# Correct using ContentStreamDataSource in DIH

Tags: search, solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

Solr documentation briefly mentions that ContentStreamDataSource can be used as a data source in the DIH config. No any other guidelines of hints are provided, so I expected that the following config is enough.

```
<dataConfig>
<datasource name="streamsrc" type="ContentStreamDataSource" loggerLevel="TRACE" />
<document>
    <entity
        stream="true"
        name="streamxml"
        datasource="streamsrc1"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        rootEntity="true"
        forEach="/books/book"
        transformer="TemplateTransformer" >
            <field column="load" template="some static payload"/>
            <field column="b_title" xpath="/books/book/name"/>
    </entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

and the following request will perform the procedure of full import taking the data source from the stream of the current request:

```
curl -X POST \
http://xxx.yyy.zzz/xmlimport \
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----    WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
-F 'stream.body=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>
 <name>NAME1</name>
 </book>
 <book>
<name>NAME2</name>
</book>
</books>' \
-F commit=true \
-F debug=true \
-F clean=false \
-F command=full-import
```

However Solr raises exception during processing:

> Full Import failed:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: No
>   dataSource :null available for entity :streamxml Processing Document #
>   1     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:271)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler.handleRequestBody(DataImportHandler.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:195)
>     at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)    at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:711)
>     at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:517)

Any suggestions for implementing that scenario ?

Comment: Your data source names differ at least: `datasource="streamsrc1"` vs `name="streamsrc"`

Comment: Thank you for the note,  indeed I tried to substitute  datasource="streamsrc" by datasource="streamsrc1" during the tests. The same Solr exception is raised.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

The problem was in the improper name of the xml tag for the data source. It is case-sensitive, so the correct name is `<dataSource...` instead of  `<datasource...` .